# Determine the structure of all finite sets $A$ of integers such that $|A| = k$ and $|2A| = 2k + 1$.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, additive-combinatorics, inverse-problems, sumset

An exercise in Nathanson's text: *Additive Number Theory, Inverse problems and the geometry of sumsets* is the following (Excercise 16, P.No.37):

**Determine the structure of all finite sets $A$ of integers such that $|A| = k$ and $|2A| = 2k + 1$.**

**Here $2A = \{a + b: a, b \in A\}$.**

By a theorem of Freiman (which states that ***if $A$ is set of $k \geq 3$ integers, and if $|2A| = 2k -1 + b \leq 3k - 4,$ then $A$ is a subset of an arithmetic progression of length $k + b \leq 2k - 3$*** [see the above mentioned Nathanson text, Theorem 1.16, P.No. 28]), it follows that the set $A$ must be a subset of an arithmetic progression of length $k + 2$, that is, in normalized form, we must have $A \subseteq [0, k+ 1]$, where $[a, b]$ denote the interval of integers $\{n \in \Bbb Z: a \leq n \leq b\}$. Since $|A| = k$, we must have $A = [0, k+1] \setminus \{c, d\}$ for some $0 \leq c < d \leq {k + 1}$. So, we need to determine all possible values of $c$ and $d$ so that $|2A| = 2k + 1$. I have examined several cases. But number of cases seems large. Is there any shorter way to do this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $2A$?  Is it $A+A=\{a+a'\,|\,a\text{ and }a'\text{ are in }A\}$?  Maybe you should also state what "a theorem of Freiman" is saying.

Comment: What is the definition of $2A$? Please add this to your question.

Comment: @Batominovski Thanks! I have edited the qquestion and have included the definition of $2A$ now.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks! I have edited the qquestion and have included the definition of $2A$ now.

Comment: What does "a theorem of Freiman" say?

Comment: @Batominovski Now I have included the statement of Freiman's theorem in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo error in the question. I have corrected the cardinality $|2A| = 2k + 1$ which was wrongly written $|2A| = k + 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $[a,b]:=\{a,a+1,a+2,\ldots,b-1,b\}$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a\leq b$ (if $a>b$, then $[a,b]:=\emptyset$).  For the set $A$ to exist, $k\geq 4$ must be true.

---

First, we deal with the case $k=4$, whence $|A+A|=9$.  We may suppose without loss of generality that $A=\{0,a,b,c\}$ with $0<a<b<c$.  Then,
$$A+A=\{0,a,2a,a+b,2b,b+c,2c\}\cup\{b,c\}\cup\{a+c\}\,.$$
Since $S:=\{0,a,2a,a+b,2b,b+c,2c\}$ already has $7$ distinct elements, the two extra elements can only come from two of the three expressions $b$, $c$, and $a+c$.

**Case I:** $A=S\cup\{b,c\}$.  Then, $a+c$ must be equal to $2b$.  Therefore, $a$, $b$, and $c$ form an arithmetic progression.  That is, $A=\{0,a,a+d,a+2d\}$ for some positive integers $a$ and $d$.  This gives
$$A+A=\{0,a,a+d,a+2d,2a,2a+d,2a+2d,2a+4d\}\,,$$
but as $|A+A|=9$, we need $d\notin\left\{a,\dfrac{a}{2}\right\}$.

**Case II:** $A=S\cup\{a+c,b\}$.  Then, $c$ must belong in $S$.  Hence, $c\in\{2a,a+b,2b\}$.

- If $c=2a$, then $A=\{0,a,b,2a\}$, so
  $$A+A=\{0,a,b,2a,a+b,2b,3a,2a+b,4a\}\,.$$
  Note that we need $b<2a$ and $b\neq \dfrac{3a}{2}$.
- If $c=a+b$, then $A=\{0,a,b,a+b\}$, so
  $$A+A=\{0,a,b,2a,a+b,2a+b,2b,a+2b,2a+2b\}\,.$$
  We require $b\neq 2a$.
- If $c=2b$, then $A=\{0,a,b,2b\}$, so
  $$A+A=\{0,a,b,2a,a+b,2b,a+2b,3b,4b\}\,.$$
  We require $b\neq 2a$.

**Case III:** $A=S\cup\{c,a+c\}$.  Then, $b$ must belong in $S$, making $b=2a$ the only possibility.  Thus, $A=\{0,a,2a,c\}$ with $c>2a$, whence
$$A+A=\{0,a,2a,3a,4a,a+c,2a+c,2c\}\,.$$

---

Now assume that $k\geq 5$.  As you claimed (I did not read the book, so I hope there is no mistake at this step), we may assume that
$$A=[0,c-1]\cup[c+1,d-1]\cup[d+1,k+1]$$
for some $c,d\in[0,k+1]$ such that $c<d$.  Observe that $(c,d)$ cannot be equal to $(0,1)$, $(k,k+1)$, or $(0,k+1)$ (otherwise, $A$ is an arithmetic progression of length $k$, so that $A+A$ has $2k-1$ elments).

**Case I:** $c=0$.  Then, $2\leq d\leq k$ and $A=[1,d-1]\cup[d+1,k+1]$.  This gives
$$A+A=[2,2d-2]\cup[d+2,d+k]\cup[2d+2,2k+2]\subseteq [2,2k+2]\,.$$
Because $[2,2k+2]$ has exactly $2k+1$ elements, we get $A+A=[2,2k+2]$.  This shows that $2d-2\geq (d+2)-1$ and $d+k\geq (2d+2)-1$.  That is, $3\leq d\leq k-1$.

**Case II:** $d=k+1$.  Using a similar argument as Case I, we obtain $2\leq c\leq k-2$.

**Case III:** $d=c+1$ with $1\leq c\leq k-1$.  Then, $A=[0,c-1]\cup[c+2,k+1]$.  That is,
$$A+A=[0,2c-2]\cup[c+2,c+k]\cup [2c+4,2k+2]\,.$$
Hence, $A+A\subseteq [0,2k+2]$ and $[0,2k+2]\setminus(A+A)$ contains two elements.

- If $c=1$, then $A+A=\{0\}\cup[3,k+1]\cup[6,2k+2]=\{0\}\cup [3,2k+2]$ (since $k\geq 4$).  Therefore, $A+A$ has $2k+1$ elements.
- If $c=k-1$, then $A+A=[0,2k-1]\cup\{2k+2\}$ (since $k\geq 4$).  Therefore, $A+A$ has $2k+1$ elements.
- If $2\leq c\leq k-2$, then the two elements of $[0,2k+2]\setminus(A+A)$ must be $2c-1$ and $c+k+1$, which have to be less than $c+2$ and $2c+4$, respectively.  This means $2c-1\leq (c+2)-1$ or $c\leq 2$, and $c+k+1\leq (2c+4)-1$ or $c\geq k-2$  That is, $k-2\leq c\leq 2$.  Hence, $k=4$, which is a contradiction.

**Case IV:** $1\leq c\leq k-2$ and $c+2\leq d\leq k$. We then see that
$$\begin{align}A+A&=\big[0,2c-2\big]\cup[c+1,c+d-2]\cup [d+1,c+k]\\&\phantom{aaaaa}\cup [2c+2,2d-2]\cup[c+d+2,d+k]\cup[2d+2,2k+2]\,,\end{align}$$
which is a subset of $[0,2k+2]$.  Since $|A+A|=2k+1$, the set $B:=[0,2k+2]\setminus(A+A)$ has two elements.

- If $c=1$, then $$A+A=\{0\}\cup[2,d-1]\cup[d+1,k+1]\cup[4,2d-2]\cup[d+3,d+k]\cup[2d+2,2k+2]\,.$$  Thus, $1\in B$.  If $4\leq d\leq k-1$, then $$[2,d-1]\cup[d+1,k+1]\cup[4,2d-2]\cup[d+3,d+k]\cup[2d+2,2k+2]=[2,2k+1]\,,$$ which leads to a contradiction.  Hence, $d=3$ or $d=k$.  If $d=3$, then
  $$A+A=\{0,2\}\cup[4,2k+2]\,,$$
  which has $2k+1$ elements.  If $d=k$, then
  $$A+A=\{0\}\cup[2,2k]\cup\{2k+2\}\,,$$
  which also has $2k+1$ elements.
- If $d=k$, then similarly to the former subcase, we can see that either $c=1$ or $c=k-2$.  The case $(c,d)=(1,k)$ has already been covered in the previous subcase.  In the case $(c,d)=(k-2,k)$, we have $A=[0,k-3]\cup\{k-1,k+1\}$, so
  $$A+A=[0,2k-2]\cup\{2k,2k+2\}\,,$$
  which has $2k+1$ elements.
- If $2\leq c\leq k-3$ and $c+2\leq d\leq k-1$, then
  $$[0,2c-2]\cup[c+1,c+d-2]\cup[d+1,c+k]=[0,c+k]$$
  and
  $$[c+d+2,d+k]\cup[2d+2,2k+2]=[c+d+2,2k+2]\,.$$
  However, $[0,c+k]\cup[c+d+2,2k+2]=[0,2k+2]$.  This subcase is impossible.

---

Here is the summary of all possible sets $A\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, where $k\geq 4$ is an integer, such that $|A|=k$ with $|A+A|=2k+1$.  The set $A$ must be an affine transformation of one of the following sets $A'$ (that is, $A=\{px+q\,|\,x\in A'\}$ for some fixed $p\in\mathbb{Z}_{\neq 0}$ and $q\in\mathbb{Z}$):

- $k=4$ and $A':=\{0,a,a+d,a+2d\}$, where $d\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\setminus\left\{a,\dfrac{a}{2}\right\}$ and $\gcd(a,d)=1$;
- $k=4$ and $A':=\{0,a,b,2a\}$, where $b\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\setminus\left\{\dfrac{a}{2},\dfrac{3a}{2},2a\right\}$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$;
- $k=4$ and $A':=\{0,a,b,a+b\}$, where $b\in\mathbb{Z}_{>a}\setminus\{2a\}$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$;
- $k\geq 5$ and $A':=[0,c-1]\cup[c+1,k]$, where $2\leq c\leq k-2$;
- $k\geq 5$ and $A':=\{0\}\cup[2,k+1]$;
- $k\geq 5$ and $A':=\{0,2\}\cup[4,2k+2]$;
- $k\geq 5$ and $A':=\{0\}\cup[2,k-1]\cup\{k+1\}$.

Comment: Thank you. The all possible sets will be the sets determined in the above solution and their affine transforms.

Comment: For $k = 4$, the theorem of Freiman is not applicable in our case, because $2k + 1 \not \leq 3k - 4$ for $k = 4$. So, we can not say that $A$ is a subset of $[0, k + 1]$ in case of $k = 4$.

Comment: @Rajkumar  I improved the answer to deal with the case $k=4$.